# Applying style to alert in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I want to provide `style` to `alert box`, my `alert` is in `controller` and I don't know how to apply `style` on `alert`

My html code is:

```
<div ng-app="myApp"> 
    <div ng-controller="TableCtrl"> 
      <h1>hi</h1> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Link are provided and are working fine the controller is as below:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

 myApp.controller('TableCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {  

    alert("page is loaded");

}]);
```

Instead of showing a system designed alert I want to change it .

Comment: Provide some example & code

Comment: provide code snippets so that we can help u

Comment: You can't style alert, you have to use use some other alert from any famous UI-Ftamwork like bootstrap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `alert` method only takes a message parameter thus **you can't change the design** of it. Consider using a UI-Framework like *bootstrap* or *material* and use a **modal window** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Like @MartinBrandl mentioned, you can't change the UI style of the browsers inbuilt alert but you can use some other library like:

1. http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/
2. http://oitozero.github.io/ngSweetAlert/#/home